# Два массива, второй зависим от первого

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть массив int [] lvl, который можно менять количество элементов и значения через Inspector в Юнити. Нужно создать второй массив int[] keys, Length которого зависит от Length первого (lvl), т.е. такая же длина. Еще во втором массиве keys значения должны быть 0, потом 3, 6 и т.д., т.е прибавляется по 3. Как такое сделать, я запутался в циклах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тогда ваш массив Keys, можно сделать методом возвращающим значение в виде массива:

```
 private int[] Keys(int[] lvl)
 { 
   var res = new int[lvl.Lenght];
   for(int i=0;i<lvl.Lenght;i++)
    {
       res[i]=i*3;
    }
    return res;
 }
```

надеюсь что ответ вас удовлетворил.

Comment: я немножко поправил вопрос, lvl это int, и у него заранее неизвестна длина массива, а задается в самом Unity, чтоб с инспектора потом можно было контролировать. Просто **public int[] lvl;**

Comment: @PinPin поправил

Answer (score 4):

Можно через LINQ:

```
var lvlArray=new int[10];
var newArray=lvlArray.Select((val,i) =>i*3 ).ToArray()
```